# Windows Phone WebBrowser - onClick javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control, windows-phone, href

I have some problem with javascript while using WebBrowser control on WindowsPhone 7.8. When I'm using `href="#"` onClick method works fine, but when i change it to `href="javascript:;"` then onClick method doesn't work. I have tried to use it in WindowsPhone web browser and the is no problems, both links works correctly.

Here is full code of my test page (http://klamborowski.pl/test/js.html):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl">
<head>
<title>
</title>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2" />

<script type="text/javascript">function post_to_url() {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "http://stackoverflow.com/");

    document.body.appendChild(form);form.submit();
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<b>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="post_to_url();">Click <br>here - javascript:;</a> <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="#" onclick="post_to_url();">Click <br>here - #</a> <br>
</b>
</body>
</html>
```

and C# code using it:

```
myWebBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
myWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://klamborowski.pl/test/js.html"));
```

Thanks in advance for any hints and help.

EDIT:
This is only example page. In my real project I'm using third party page with payments (which contains `href="javascript:;"`) and I can't make any changes to it.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity: why using a `javascript:;` like rather than `#`?

Comment: This is only example page. In my real project I'm using third party page with payments and I can't make any changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the `onclick` in **first position** in your link, before anything else.

```
<a onclick="post_to_url();" href="javascript:;" >
```

don't ask me why but it worked for me.